# How to fech data api from https://covid19.mathdro.id/api?? im tryin to dipslay this data in my app.js

Tags: javascript, expo

```
import React from 'react';

import {View , Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';

class Global extends React.Component{

    constructor(){

        super();

       this.state = {


          global: [],

           refreshing: false



       }

   }



   renderItem = ({item}) => (

   <View style={{ padding: 20, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#000'}}>

       <Text> Positif: {item.confirmed.value}   </Text>

       <Text> Sembuh: {item.recovered}  </Text>

       <Text> Meninggal: {item.deaths}  </Text>



   </View>



   )



   onRefresh = () => {

       this.getDataApi();



   }

   componentDidMount = () => {

       this.getDataApi();

   }



   getDataApi = async () => {

       this.setState({ refreshing: true})

       fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api')

       .then(response => response.json())

       .then(json => this.setState({  global: json.confirmed.value }))





   }





   render(){
        console.log(this.state.global);



       return (

           <View>



           <FlatList 

               data={this.state.global}

               keyExtractor= {item => item.toString()}

               renderItem= {this.renderItem}

               refreshing={this.state.refreshing}

               onRefresh={this.onRefresh}

               />

           </View>

       )

   }
}


export default Global;
```

**This is My code**

Comment: Need more information, what is currently happening with your code? Can you post the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

The response you are getting from the API is an object and there is on need to use of flatlist as you are just showing three texts here, you can do something like this:

```
 render(){
       return (
           <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
               {this.state.global.confirmed != undefined ? <Text> Positif: {this.state.global.confirmed.value}   </Text> : null}
               {this.state.global.confirmed != undefined ? <Text> Sembuh: {this.state.global.recovered.value}   </Text> : null}
               { this.state.global.confirmed != undefined ? <Text> Meninggal: {this.state.global.deaths.value}   </Text> : null}
           </View>
```

Hope this helps!